How to get a string array in an Excel cell and use as a reference
I have the following formula:
=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;{"CHN";"SGP";"AUS";"MYS"}))
where Country is a Column.
I would like to have a cell containing the array of countries I'm searching for.
So for instance cell P3 would have a value like:
{"CHN";"SGP";"AUS";"MYS"}
and the formula would become something like
=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;P3))
But whatever I tried in cell P3
{"CHN";"SGP";"AUS";"MYS"}
"CHN";"SGP";"AUS";"MYS"
"CHN","SGP","AUS","MYS"

or modifying the formula to something like
=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;{P3}))
I can't seem to find the right syntax.. hoping that it is possible.
Also tried to do something like:
=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;TEXTSPLIT(P3,",")))
but to no avail.
Thanks for helping out.

=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;TEXTSPLIT(P3,","))).... This should work if you'd use the correct syntax? You used semi-colon as your delimiter in COUNTIF() and a comma as the delimiter within TEXTSPLIT(). Therefor I suspect you should use: =SUM(COUNTIF(Country;TEXTSPLIT(P3;","))). Works for me at least assuming P3 == CHN,SGP,AUS,MYS. If that was not the issue then you probably just need to get rid of the quotes in P3.

Yes it worked. After adjusting the right separator and removing the quotes it worked.

You used semi-colon as your delimiter in COUNTIF() and a comma as the delimiter within TEXTSPLIT(). Therefor I suspect you should use:
=SUM(COUNTIF(Country;TEXTSPLIT(P3;",")))

Works for me at least assuming P3 == CHN,SGP,AUS,MYS.
If that was not the issue then you probably just need to get rid of the quotes in P3.

You can try
=SUM(MAP(country,LAMBDA(q,REDUCE(0,TEXTSPLIT(P3,","),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=q,1,a))))))

where country represents your column of countries and P3 represents a list of values separated by a comma.

After modifying your comma separators to semicolumns, I also got this working. If @JvdV adds his comment as answer I will choose that one as the accepted answer because that is for me more understandable then yours but nevertheless thanks for helping out and for providing a different approach.
